# Mac OS X address of PTE

Tags: macos, memory, kernel, virtual

In Windows, one can access the PTE structures for a specific virtual address by constructing
the address of the PTE itself.
This is because all PTES are mapped in virtual address space starting at certain address.

Is this also the case with Mac OS X?
I mean, can I have access to the PTE for a given virtual address?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but only in kernel mode of course, through the "pmap" layer. You will need the relevant value of CR3 (i.e. the process (or kernel) context), since different values of CR3 imply different page tables. Note, however, that these aren't exposed KPI (Kernel Public/Programming Interfaces), so it will take crafting a kext that would be very specific per kernel version. It's not entirely clear *why* in all this you'd need the PTE, since xnu is virtual from about the second line of start.S - but it is nonetheless possible.